# how magento 2 customer password hash decrypt

Tags: magento2, customer, password, encryption-key

Hi team is there any way to decrypt customer password hash programmatically If any one knows please help in that

tried  `$objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface::class)->decrypt('3ab0670c9c8c735a5f19ad21f0edb2c3:xVQMVlk23owdkQDp7AYAQGrI5TLotz48:0');`

but not working getting empty

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php
...

protected $customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    ...
}
...
$customerEmail = "customerEmail@example.com"; // add customer email address
$websiteId = "1"; // add your website id

$customer = $this->customerRepository->get($customerEmail, $websiteId);
$customerId = $customer->getId();
$customerPassword = "customerPassowrd123";
try {
    $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $customerPassword);
    // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Exceptions.ThrowCatch
    echo 'Customer account authenticated successfully';
} catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
    throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid email or password.'));
}
```

Comment: I am asking how to decrypt password. $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $customerPassword); this is checking password. Here not decrypting password i want decrypt password

Comment: Magento 2 doesn't provide such functionality to decrypt the customer's password. But you can log in to the customer account by editing the customer password field from the database which isn't a recommended method.